# Kotlin using lambda as initializer

Tags: kotlin, properties, initialization, readability

So I have the following dilemma. This is not a question regarding something that doesn't work but rather about what would be more elegant/good practice and why.

So, we know abut `init` blocks, initialization logic goes in them. Maybe you open a file or read some constant from a config file, maybe you set some properties based on some more complicated algorithm that uses the constructor arguments.

However, what if one/some of your properties do require a little bit of logic, trivial logic such as validating an argument or things like this. And this logic is  only related to that particular property, no interaction with other properties?

For example:

```
class MyCircularQueue(k: Int) {

    private val arr = { 
        if (k < 1) 
            throw IllegalArgumentException("k must be at least 1") 
        else  
            Array(k) { 0 }
    }()

    private var head = 0
    private var tail = 0
    private var empty = true

}
```

Here `arr` needs to be initialized to an array of `0`s, but obviously there is a problem if `k` is less than 1. A really short initialization logic is needed, just a simple check that throws an exception or initializes the array. No interaction with other properties, no complex logic, just an extremely trivial check or logic.

In this case I was wondering if it wouldn't be better to place the trivial initialization logic in a "makeshift" code block (a lambda called on the spot). The  benefit would be that the declaration and initialization logic would be in the same place, not separated without need and I think this way it is more readable.

So after I wrote this I wondered if anyone else had this problem for very simple initialization logic but I couldn't really find anything about it.

So bottom line: Is this okay? Is is good practice, or at least *not* bad practice? Does it make sense? And is there a nicer and/or official way to do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function workaround is not necessary, `if` is an expression and returns a value, so it can be simplified:

```
private val arr =
    if (k < 1)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("k must be at least 1")
    else
        Array(k) { 0 }
```

Alternatively, Kotlin comes with a lot of functional APIs in the standard library which can help creating concise one liners. In this case, you could do:

```
private val arr =
     k.takeIf { it > 0 }?.let { Array(k) { 0 } } ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("k must be at least 1")
```

Comment: It completely escaped my mind in that moment that if was actually an expression, thanks! And that second method is just wow

Answer (score 3):

As s1m0nw1's answer says, you don't really need it here, but it can be useful when you want e.g. local variables in your initializer.

In that case, instead of using `()` to call the lambda, I'd use [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) which will inline it nicely and is more visible, e.g.

```
private val arr = run {
  val temp1 = ...
  val temp2 = ...
  arrayOf(temp1, temp2)
}
```

Comment: Forgot about `run`. Thank you!